Alter table and update existing rows
For the life of me I can't seem to get this simple script to run as design.
I need to be able to add a column to a table that has over 1 million rows and set this field to a value based off a date.
ALTER TABLE dbo.sample
ADD [IS_CURRENT] BIT
;

UPDATE dbo.sample
SET [IS_CURRENT] = 0 
WHERE [LOAD_DATE] < '01-jan-25'
;

UPDATE dbo.sample
SET [IS_CURRENT] = 0 
WHERE [LOAD_DATE] >= CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(DAY,-60,GETDATE())), 0) AS DATE)
;

This will work if I run each statement separately, but when I attempt to execute all at once I receive the error "Invalid column name".

Side notes: (1) If using SQL Server 2022 or later, you may find the DATE_TRUNC() function useful. (2) Subtracting 60 days from a date is not the same as subtracting two months, if that is your intent. For example, subtracting 60 days from January 31 will give you December 2 (1 month back). Subtracting 60 days from March 1 may give you December 31 (3 months back).  See this db<>fiddle.

SQL is a pre-compiled language, so you will get a compile error if the column doesn't exist when you submit the batch.
In SSMS and other client apps, you can put GO on a separate line to split batches.
Note also how I've combined the two UPDATEs, and improved the date handling logic, and used a deterministic date format
ALTER TABLE dbo.sample
ADD [IS_VALID] BIT
;
GO
UPDATE dbo.sample
SET IS_VALID = 0 
WHERE LOAD_DATE < '20250101'
   OR LOAD_DATE >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) AS date)
;

In a procedure you can instead use dynamic SQL
ALTER TABLE dbo.sample
ADD [IS_VALID] BIT
;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
UPDATE dbo.sample
SET IS_VALID = 0 
WHERE LOAD_DATE < ''20250101''
   OR LOAD_DATE >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) AS date)
;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;  -- add parameters if necessary

